# Анонимная функция

Tags: jquery

Есть кусок кода из учебника:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#open").click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault(); 
 });
});
```

Первая строка дает команду ждать загрузки всего html документа. Но разве .ready по умолчанию не делает это сама?
И второй вопрос. У события click есть функция evt. Могу ли я не использовать ее, а просто сделать анонимную функцию?:

```
 $("#open").click(function() {
        preventDefault(); 
     });
```

Не пинайте за глупые вопросы, я только учусь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут

```
$("#open").click(function(evt) {
```

**evt** не функция, как вы пишите, а объект, содержащий данные о произошедшем событии. И в дальнейшем этот объект нужен, чтобы применить к нему метод **preventDefault()** тут

```
evt.preventDefault();
```

> [event.preventDefault()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_event)
>   Отменяет выполнение события. Например, при "клике" по ссылке, переход по ней не произойдет, если внутри обработчика будет вызван этот метод.

preventDefault() не может быть вызван без привязки к объекту события.

Answer (score 1):

Функция $.ready дожидается построения DOM дерева, происходит это после полной загрузки HTML страницы, но до полной её загрузки. Когда это дерево элементов построено, вызывается переданная в качестве аргумента функция. В ней вы производите поиск элемента с id=open, к этому моменту элемент (тег) должен существовать. Поэтому есть пара вариантов: дожидаться полного построения дерева как в первом кусочке кода, либо поместить второй кусочек кода после создания обозначенного элемента, например, прямо перед закрывающим тегом `</body>`.

Comment: спасибо, а по поводу анонимной функции, или ее обязательно называть?

Comment: Анонимные функции — это такие, у которых не указано имя между словом function и скобками. В ваших примерах все функции анонимные.

Comment: @mymedia, автор вопроса спрашивал совершенно не о том, что вы написали в своем ответе!